# Getting error during Google authentication process through omniauth in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm constructing an app in Ruby on Rails and trying to give users the ability to sign in using Google. I followed [this](https://medium.com/@jenn.leigh.hansen/google-oauth2-for-rails-ba1bcfd1b863) article's setup instructions and set up the entire authentication procedure, but every time I click to the callback URL, I get this issue.

undefined method `expired?' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #92):

```
        else
          self.access_token = build_access_token
          self.access_token = access_token.refresh! if access_token.expired?
          super
        end
      rescue ::OAuth2::Error, CallbackError => e
```

Here are some files from my project.

1. routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 root "loginpage#login"
 get "/home" , to: "homepage#home"
 get "/login",  to: "loginpage#login"
 get "/auth/google_oauth2/callback" , to: 'sessions#create'
end
```

2. session_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
   def create
       buyer = Buyer.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
    #    puts "OmniAuth response: #{request.env['omniauth.auth']}"
    logger.info("omniauth response: #{request.env['omniauth.auth']}")
       if buyer.valid?
        session[:buyerid] = buyer.buyerid
        redirect_to user_path(buyer)
       else
        redirect_to '/login'
       end
   end
end
```

3.omniauth.rb

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :google_oauth2, ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'], ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'],provider_ignores_state: true
    end
```

4.Model file(buyer.rb)

```
class Buyer < ApplicationRecord
    self.table_name = 'buyer'
    has_secure_password
    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, format: {with:  /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/, message: 'Invalid email'}
    def self.from_omniauth(response)
        puts "response #{response}"
        Buyer.find_or_create_by(uid:response[:uid],provider:response[:provider]) do |u|
            u.fname = response[:info][:name]
            u.email = response[:info][:email]
            u.password = SecureRandom.hex(15)
        end
    end
 end
```

and this is how i am giving button to user in ui

```
 <%= link_to 'Sign in with Google', "/auth/google_oauth2/callback" %>
```

please help!!

Comment: So either `build_access_token` returns `nil` (what does that method look like?) or there is a `access_token` setter method, but the getter method does not exist or behaves unexpected (How did you implement those?).

Comment: The error coming in the default omniauth file from my side i just followed that article which i mentioned in the question.